# Autoware & LGSVL: Vehicle Not Moving

Tags: simulation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have been working with Autoware and LGSVL simulator by following the steps [here](https://www.lgsvlsimulator.com/docs/autoware-instructions/) to do a simulation with LGSVL simulator. I am using two different machines for running Autoware (running from source instead of docker) and the simulator. I have both the machines on a local network and gave the Autoware machine's IP address (It was something like 192.168.0.xx:9090) as bridge connection string in the simulator's `Map & Vehicles` tab. Here is the configuration of two machines:

**Machine running the LGSVL simulator (2020.06 version) has the following configuration:**

1. Intel i7-2600 processor at 3.4GHz - 4 core processor which can run two threads per core (basically an 8 core machine)
2. 16 GB RAM
3. 500GB Hard Drive
4. GeForce GTX 1650 graphics card
5. Running on Windows 10

**Machine running the Autoware 1.12.0 (source code with CUDA build) has the following configuration:**:

1. Intel i7-2600 processor at 3.4GHz - 4 core processor which can run two threads per core (basically an 8 core machine)
2. 16 GB RAM
3. 1TB Hard Drive
4. GeForce GTX 1050 Ti graphics card
5. Running on Ubuntu 16.04

I have loaded all the launch files in the RunTime Manager for BorregasAve and clicked on RVIZ button as shown in the below figures. Although, with some errors on the terminal.

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

After that, I have started the lgsvl simulator in the other machine with the following settings as shown below:

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

After I clicked the start button, I was able to see that the simulator was connected to the Autoware machine as shown in the below image and then I have hit play button on the simulator:

[image: image description]

I have also selected all these from the computing tab:
vel_pose_connect,
lane_rule,
lane_stop,
lane_select,
obstacle_void,
velocity_set,
pure_pursuit,
twist_filter as shown in image below:

[image: image description]

I was able to initiate the 2D pose estimate and then gave a 2D nav goal as shown in image below:

[image: image description]

`I have waited for 10 to 15 mins and the vehicle does not move at all.`

Here is the screenshot of the terminal with some failed messages.

[image: image description]

Please help me if I am doing anything wrong here.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363873/autoware-&-lgsvl:-vehicle-not-moving/) by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2020-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it by upgrading to Autoware 14.0. That fixed everything.

---

Originally posted by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) with karma: 64 on 2020-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1